# Prove $\int {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau= {\operatorname{sinc}}(\lambda-\nu ).$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to prove the following relation. For any real numbers $\lambda$ and $\nu$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau= {\operatorname{sinc}}(\lambda-\nu ).
\end{equation}
**This is my proof.** 
$$4\pi^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau=$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty {2\pi} {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big) {2\pi} {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)d\tau=$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {2\pi} {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\lambda\big)\overline{ {2\pi} {\operatorname{sinc}}\big({\tau}-\nu\big)}d\tau=$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal F( u_\lambda)(\xi)\overline{\mathcal F( u_\nu)}(\xi)d\xi$$
which becomes, solving the Fourier transform
\begin{align}
&=2\pi \int_{-\infty}^\infty  u_\lambda(\xi)\overline{( u_\nu)}(\xi)d\xi \notag \\
&=2\pi \int_{ -{\pi}}^{{\pi} }e^{i (\lambda-\nu)\xi} d\xi \notag \\
&=4\pi^2 {{\sin \pi\big(\lambda-\nu)}\over{\pi(\lambda-\nu) }}\notag \\
&=4\pi^2  {\operatorname{sinc}}(\lambda-\nu )
\end{align}

This statement can be proved in other ways?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is probably the neatest proof for this fact. The Fourier transform of sinc is a box function and has only the values 0 and 1. Therefore it is its own square. For the sinc function, this means that when you form its convolution with itself, you get the same function back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $~I(k)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x-a)}{x-a}\cdot\frac{\sin(x-b)}{x-b}~e^{-k~(x-a)(x-b)}~dx\quad=>\quad I'(k)~=~?$

Of course, this will require some knowledge about [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) and [Gaussian integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).